# What's the proper way to encode PANTONE colours in SVG files?

Tags: colors, svg, color-space, pantone

I have an application that spits out SVG images, and for printing purposes, I would want it to produce properly encoded PANTONE colours (where known). The SVG specs are not very detailed in how the output should look, and I haven't been able to find any examples online, despite some searching.

My attempts so far don't work for display purposes (at least not in Google Chrome), so I am probably off here, but thus far, I have tried [this](http://bl.ocks.org/d/3123914/italy.svg) ([gist](https://gist.github.com/3123914)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This file is an attempt at specifying the Italian flag with the -->
<!-- proper Pantone colours, as noted in the Wikipedia talk page, at -->
<!--  http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File_talk:Flag_of_Italy.svg  -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.2" viewBox="0 0 3 2">
<!-- Verde  --><rect fill="#009246 icc-color(17-6153)" width="1" height="2"/>
<!-- Bianco --><rect fill="#f1f2f1 icc-color(11-0601)" width="1" height="2" x="1"/>
<!-- Rosso  --><rect fill="#ce2b37 icc-color(18-1662)" width="1" height="2" x="2"/>
</svg>
```

I probably need to specify what colour profile this is, along the [SVG spec's notes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/WD-SVGPrintPrimer12-20070501/#color), but I am not sure quite how. Input appreciated.

Comment: See this editors draft of SVG Colors, might make things a bit more clear: http://dev.w3.org/SVG/modules/color/publish/SVGColor.html.

Comment: Thanks; that's a very useful starting point! http://dev.w3.org/SVG/modules/color/test/svg/paint-icc-001.svg seems a fair example of how it's supposed to be done, linking an external ICC profile (PANTONE, in my case) and then listing colours similar to my example above - which Chrome doesn't seem to support yet.